# SELECT multiple values to the same key in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I have two tables in the following structure

**table_1**

```
uid | name | age
1   | John | 24
2   | Adam | 35
3   | Sara | 26
```

**table_2**

```
id | uid | meta_key | meta_value
1  | 2   | location | NY
2  | 2   | school   | NYU
3  | 3   | Location | NY
4  | 3   | school   | XYZ
6  | 1   | location | NY
6  | 1   | school   | NYU
```

What I am trying to do is to select the users from table_1 where their location is NY and school is NYU

here is the query I tried using with no luck

```
SELECT
  tabl_1.uid
FROM `tabl_1`, `tabl_2`
WHERE
  tabl_1.uid = tabl_2.uid
  AND table_2.meta_key IN ('location', 'school')
  AND table_2.meta_value IN ('NY', 'NYU')
ORDER BY tabl_1.uid ASC
```

I have looked everywhere without any luck, if you have a query that works or a link to a solution that would much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try

```
SELECT t1.uid
FROM tabl_1 t1 INNER JOIN tabl_2 t2
ON t1.uid = t2.uid AND t2.meta_key = 'location' AND t2.meta_value = 'NY'
INNER JOIN tabl_2 t3
ON t1.uid = t3.uid AND t3.meta_key = 'school' AND t3.meta_value = 'NYU'
```

Check result on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f35ef/1/0

Answer (score 1):

Try:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc913c/27

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
(
  SELECT a.uid, a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.meta_key, b.meta_value) AS mkv 
  FROM table_1 a
  LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON b.uid = a.uid 
  GROUP BY a.uid, a.name
) AS t
WHERE 
  t.mkv IN ("schoolNYU,locationNY");
```

Comment: Nice thought, but not sure if it would be as efficient as the join

Comment: Updated the answer - forgot order; for efficient - you might be right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT table_1.Uid
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.Uid = table_2.Uid
WHERE (table_2.meta_key = 'location' AND table_2.meta_value = 'NY')
AND (table_2.meta_key = 'school' AND table_2.meta_valaye = 'NYU')
```